# How to write nltk grammar to check but not capture some text

Tags: regex, nltk, grammar

I have 2 sentences:

```
procedure, when performed, some other text
procedure, limited, some other text
```

I want to select VBN with comma after it:

```
import nltk

sents = [
    ['procedure', ',', 'when', 'performed', ',', 'some', 'other', 'text'],
    ['procedure', ',', 'limited', ',', 'some', 'other', 'text']
]
tokens = [nltk.pos_tag(x) for x in sents]

grammar = r"""
  CHUNK: {<VBN><,>}
"""
chunker = nltk.RegexpParser(grammar)

for x in tokens:
    tree = chunker.parse(x)
    print tree
```

It works:

```
(S procedure/NN ,/, when/WRB (CHUNK performed/VBN ,/,) some/DT other/JJ text/NN)
(S procedure/NN ,/, (CHUNK limited/VBN ,/,) some/DT other/JJ text/NN)
```

But I need to select VBN when it **wrapped** by commas. Some kind of `re.compile(r'(?:,)\s*([a-z]+ed),')`

There is any way to use `(?:...)` in RegexpParser grammar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case need to move forward comma out of `{}`:

```
grammar = r"""
  CHUNK: <,>{<VBN><,>}
"""
```

In this case system will do exactly what I need.